# How can I disable kendo TabStrip tab scrollable with Tag Helper?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

Code with Html Helper:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
   .Name("tabstrip")
   .Scrollable(false)
```

But I don't know how to do it with Tag Helper. Any ideas?

scrollable="false" not working

```
<kendo-tabstrip name="tabstrip" tab-position="top" scrollable="false">
    <popup-animation>
        <open effects="fade:in" />
    </popup-animation>
    <items>
        <tabstrip-item text="First Tab">
            <content>
            </content>
        </tabstrip-item>
    </items>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a child tag `<scrollable />` that should be used:

```
<kendo-tabstrip name="tabstrip" tab-position="top">
  <scrollable enabled="false" />
  <popup-animation>
    <open effects="fade:in" />
  </popup-animation>
  <items>
    <tabstrip-item text="First Tab">
        <content>
        </content>
    </tabstrip-item>
  </items>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```